# How to make a paragraph text that previews a short amount then a link to expand the rest in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to be able to display a paragraph where if the text being shown is (say) over 15 lines long, then a link text will appear and if click it will expand. example:

This is a long line for here
 so i need to make more display
 but i cant so what will (More)...   <== this more link will be clicked and the rest will show up below
 this paragraph expanded to show
 the rest of it. (Close)...         <== this close link will be clicked and the rest of the page 
                                         will be hidden again

Can this be done in Flex?

Thankx again for all help and info

Here is a link example done in javascript
http://tech-cats.net/blog/examples/createParagraphPreview.html

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Was that your only question?  What have you tried to implement this? Did you have any questions about that implementation?

Comment: As Flextras said, we're not here to do this for you.  It's possible, but please do your research and be more specify about your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `mxml` as follows:

```
<mx:Label text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
truncateToFit="true"
maxWidth="100" />
```

The same thing can be achieved using actionscript like :

```
var label:Label = new Label();
label.text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
label.truncateToFit = true;
label.maxWidth = 100;
```

Then you can handle `MouseEvent.CLICK` to drop `truncateToFit` property to `false` and show up the rest of the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please edit to use Spark components instead of MX?  Also, this doesn't have a "15 line limit" and no way to expand it.